# Kivy buildozer ImportError grpc custom recipe

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I'm getting the below error when trying to package my app using buildozer (VM with Ubuntu):

`ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.so" is a 64-bit instead of a 32-bit`

Apparently this is because I need to write a custom recipe for grpcio, so I did that:

```
class GrpcioRecipe(CythonRecipe):
    version = 'master'
    url = 'https://github.com/grpc/grpc/archive/{version}.zip'
    name = 'grpcio'

    depends = ['six', 'futures', 'enum34']

recipe = GrpcioRecipe()
```

I saved the recipe as `grcpio_recipes.sh`, put it in a folder called recipes and changed the buildozer.spec file to `# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any) p4a.local_recipes = .buildozer/python-for-android/recipes`

However, I'm still getting the same error as before. Have I added the recipe to the right area - it doesn't seem like it's using my custom recipe.

[image: Requirements in buildozer.spec]

[image: Folders]

[image: Folders2]

[image: End of traceback]

[image: Traceback]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this code inside `recipes/grpcio/__init__.py`
And don't forget to add it in the requirements as well in addition to adding it as a recipe

Comment: I've already done that, the code is here: ```~/buildozer/my_app/p4a-recipes/grpcio/__init__.py``` I put a few print statements in the above code to see if it's being run but nothing prints. It might be I'm not telling buildozer to look in the right place. What should I change this section of the ```buildozer.spec``` file based on the above PATH? It's currently set to this:```# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any) p4a.local_recipes = .buildozer/python-for-android/recipes```

Comment: I just noticed the directory in my buildozer.spec file was wrong so I updated it to the following ```# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any) p4a.local_recipes = .buildozer/p4a-recipes``` but still got the same error

Comment: @CallumPurcell Are you sure you added grpcio in the requirements as well? Also showing logs might be helpful.

Comment: Yes, grpcio is part of requirements. I've edited the above to include images of the traceback, folder structure and requirements section. As I'm running it on an Ubuntu virtual machine I couldn't copy and paste the code from the traceback so used screenshots but let me know if that's needed and I'll find a way!